# Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html

js выполняется слишком  быстро как мне поставить его выполнять через время

```
   <button id="button" onclick="$(function()
{
    var chat_scroll = $('#content');
    chat_scroll.scrollTop(chat_scroll.prop('scrollHeight'));
});" >send</button>
```

не весь код

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="content"><?php include("chatGetMsg.php"); ?></div>
    <div id="textarea"><textarea id="text" name='message' maxlength="200"></textarea></div>
    <div id="send"><button id="button" onclick="$(function()
{
    var chat_scroll = $('#content');
    chat_scroll.scrollTop(chat_scroll.prop('scrollHeight'));
});" >send</button></div>  
   </div>  
    <div class="Chan"></div>
```

ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        show();
        setInterval(show, 300);

        $("#button").bind("click", function () {
            var message = $("#text").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "chatGetMsg.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {message},
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });

        function show() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "chatGetMsg.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Наверное потому что 'content' у вас не инициализирован вашим элементом. Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: я изменил тему вопроса

Comment: Может вам нужен setTimeout? Что значит "выполняется слишком быстро"?

Comment: мой ajax скрипт не успевает выполнится, как уже он скролит вниз

Comment: А вы вызывайте функцию прокрутки по окончанию ajax запроса.

Comment: логично только я js плохо знаю

Comment: а вы дайте кусок кода который выполняет ajax запрос

Comment: добавил в тему вопроса

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48831/discussion-between-noprogress-and-krasul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, решение выполнять код медленней не совсем корректно. Так как обычно хотят обратного, что бы код работал быстрей;)
Правильнее будет добавить таймер на событие.
Например, такое используют при keyup, keydown, keypress. Одно событие запускает таймер, если его значение достигло нужной величины - то выполняют какое-то событие, в противном случае, если на клавиатуру продолжают нажимать, таймер сбрасывается и начинает отсчет с нуля итд.